# Как подключится из контейнера к хосту через ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, asp.net, postgresql, docker

Дано:

1. Хост с установленным Postgres к которому можно подключиться только через ssh тунель.
2. Хост с приложением (dotnet core) которое находится в docker контейнере.

Как подкоючится приложению из контейнера к базе? Нужно внутри контейнера поднимать ssh тунель или есть дригие способы?

Comment: сделай докер с постресом и соединяйся без участия хоста

Comment: что то пока стремно базу засовывать в контейнер, бэкапы, логи, всякие настройки, как то геморно это все выглядит, у вас база в контейнере? как полет? кто может поделится опытом? как скорость работы базы в контейнере вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как подкоючится приложению из контейнера к базе?

Контейнеры по умолчанию имеют выход во внешнюю сеть, так что, до тех пор, пока постгрес у вас не висит на 127.0.0.1 и контейнеру доступна сеть - просто по айпишнику, как обычно. В противном случае, если вы на Linux, проще всего пробросить unix socket внутрь контейнера как обычный файл.

> Нужно внутри контейнера поднимать ssh тунель или есть дригие способы?

Несмотря на то, что дополнительные сетевые действия (типа проброса туннеля) могут потребоваться в некоторых сетапах, я настойчиво рекомендую избегать их, пока есть возможность - просто потому что они добавляют еще одну точку, за которой кто-то должен следить, и "база отвалилась" при таком сетапе может означать уже не только "постгрес упал", но и "порвался туннель", что может негативно сказаться на времени восстановления работоспособности.

> что то пока стремно базу засовывать в контейнер, бэкапы, логи, всякие настройки, как то геморно это все выглядит

Все примерно так же, как и на хосте. В теории могут быть проблемы со слоеной FS, все остальное должно функционировать ровно так же.

> как скорость работы базы в контейнере вообще

Если вы на Linux - абсолютно идентично скорости без контейнера. Контейнеров на самом деле не существует, "контейнер" - это абсолютно обычный прцоесс, изолированный на уровне ядра Linux.

Comment: слоеной FS — это layerfs?

Comment: @NickVolynkin то что у докера называется union fs, сборище слоев, объединенных в одну файловую систему.

Comment: пойду учить матчасть.